# Is there a php module, that would let me access OpenCL functionality of graphic card?

Tags: php, opencl

I'm looking for a way how to handle handle parallel processing on graphic cards from PHP script. It should be possible for that PHP MOD to exists, so I'm asking, if it already exist, or it is some work to do for C programmers.

Comment: Can you take a look here . it's about a PHP OpenCL extension
https://github.com/rsky/php-opencl

Comment: Looks like some C is already done, but php interface is missing. Also no documentation, I'll take deep look later, but it seems to be possible working with that and writing it's php classes on the way.